# c# windows service - Capture User Keyboard input

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm trying to capture the key press input in Windows Service

I use `KeystrokeAPI` which works fine in console application,

Here's the code in `OnStart()` of the service :

```cs
using(var api = new KeystrokeAPI()) 
{
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
    
    t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerCallback);
    t.Interval = 30000;
    t.Enabled = true;
    t.AutoReset = true;
    
    api.CreateKeyboardHook((character) => 
    {
        // Console.Write(character);
        count++;
    });
}
```

Event Handler :

```cs
protected void TimerCallback(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
{
    // Display the date/time when this method got called.
    //Console.WriteLine("In TimerCallback: " + DateTime.Now);
    //Console.WriteLine("Count Of Keys: " + count);
    
    StreamWriter sw = 
        new StreamWriter(@"d:\ChaiKeyAPILog.txt", true);
        
    sw.WriteLine();
    sw.WriteLine("In TimerCallback: " + DateTime.Now);
    sw.WriteLine("Count Of Keys: " + count);
    
    sw.Close();
    
    count = 0;
    
    // Force a garbage collection
    GC.Collect();
}
```

As I kept timer, so it displays the `Datetime` for every given interval of time, but It's not displaying the count of the pressed keys of the keyboard.

I tried writing it in `Main()` but it doesn't make any difference.

Any Help is appreciated !

Comment: So you're writing a keylogger?

Comment: yes john, writing a keylogger in Windows Service